# inheritance example not printing expected results

Tags: c++, inheritance

Trying to remember basic C++ stuff (it's been a long time), and playing with the compiler.  I created a simple base/child inheritance example.

I expected the below to output

```
index 0 is 0
index 1 is 1
index 2 is 2
```

but instead get:

```
index 0 is 0
index 1 is 2
index 2 is 0
```

Can someone point out what is obviously a poor mistake on my part?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public: 
    Base(){x=0;}
    int x;
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() { y=0;}
    int y;
};

// practicing operator definition syntax
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Base& base)
{
       ostr << base.x << endl;
       ostr << flush;
    return ostr;
}

void init(Base *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        b[i].x=i; 
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Derived arr[3];
    init(arr);
    for (int idx = 0; idx< 3; idx++)
    {
        cout << "index is " << idx << ' ' << arr[idx] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you passing to `init`?

Comment: apparently the wrong thing (see below responses)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays and polymorphism don't mix in C++.

`Derived` and `Base` objects have different sizes, any pointer arithmetic involved in you program will fail.

Your `init` method is slicing `Derived` objects in `Base` objects. The following assignment has undefined behavior, it is setting some bytes somewhere on the `Derived` object.

Consider using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>` as a replacement.

Also, your `Base` class is missing its virtual destructor, calling for more undefined behavior later.

Comment: +1 although the lack of a virtual destructor is not a problem here.

Comment: "Arrays and polymorphism don't mix...".  I was unaware of this.  I figured since an array is merely a pointer to the first object in the array, this would be similar to having stated: Base* b = new Derived[3];    Ah.... yep you all are right.  Thank you for reawakening long dead brain cells!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

An array to a derived type isn't an array to a base type! Although a pointer to a derived objects converts to a pointer to a base object, you can't use the base pointer as a pointer into an array of base objects.

The reasoning is pretty simple: when you do an operation like `array[i]` the compiler translates this to `*(array + i)` and the internal address arithmetic is done as something like `array + sizeof(T) * i` where `T` is the static type of `array`. Now, for a type `D` derived from a base type `B` it generally holds that `sizeof(B) < sizeof(D)`. As a result, if you treat an array of derived objects as an array of based objects, the index arithmetic will end up accessing elements at more or less random places in the object.